# Multiple Switches in an Array are activated when only one is pressed Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3

I am working on an attendance app that uploads and stores all of its data in firebase. Most things are currently working except that sometimes when a switch is pressed in the array of students in the club, 2 of the switches activate in the array but the information normally sent when a switch is pressed is only sent for the switch that I actually pressed.

Here is the TableView cell code:

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    class StudentCell: UITableViewCell {
        var student: Student? { didSet { self.updateUI() }}

        @IBOutlet weak var lblStudentName: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var lblStudentId: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var lblStudentAttending: UISwitch!

        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        var user: Student! {
            didSet{
            lblStudentName.text = user.FullName()
            lblStudentId.text = user.StudentId
            lblStudentAttending.isOn = false
            }
        }

        var switchReference: DatabaseReference?
        var switchHandle: DatabaseHandle?

        func stopObservation() {
            if let handle = switchHandle {
                switchReference?.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
            }
        }

        func startObservation() {
            stopObservation()

            if let uid = student?.StudentId {
                switchReference = ref.child("attendance").child(Global.shared.currentDate).child(uid)
                switchReference?.observe(.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let isOn = (snapshot.value as? Bool) ?? false
                        self?.lblStudentAttending.isOn = isOn
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        func updateUI() {
            startObservation()
            self.lblStudentName.text = self.student?.FullName() ?? ""
            self.lblStudentId.text = self.student?.StudentId ?? ""
        }

        @IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch)  {
            switchReference?.setValue(sender.isOn)
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? If you need more information lmk. TIA -Ben

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Tables reuse their cells so that they don't have to keep allocating new ones, which is expensive when the user is trying to scroll through a lot of rows quickly. You're setting up an observer for the switch in each cell, which means that you need to stop observing that switch when the cell is no longer visible. You could probably call `stopObservation()` in the cell's `prepareForReuse()` method and solve the problem.

A better solution would be to avoid observing the switch altogether, and instead use the target/action mechanism that controls typically use to trigger an action when the user changes their value. That way you don't have to worry about constantly starting and stopping observation.